# Publish or Edit an entry in a specific Channel - Publish tab empty

Tags: publish-layout

I have a website running EE 2.7.2. From yesterday, after publishing an entry, I noticed that if I edit an entry from that channel or if I try to publish a new one, the Publish tab is completely empty:

[image: publish tab empty]

The channel is correctly linked to the channel field, and in the front-end I can see all the entries from that channel.

If I click to show toolbar all the fields are unchecked, but if I check them (with the eye open) and click Save Layout, it returns unchecked:

[image: Show toolbar]

This problem occurs only with a Channel, and I don't want to delete and re-create the channel because there are dozens of entries here.

What can I do? Thank you.